# Grid Image HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a beginner in HTML, and I'm trying to create ma grid and images, and I want to flip the text over the image, but I can not. Would anyone help me? I did several tests and nothing worked. I'm studying this if I stop, and gradually I'm getting it, but this time I need help. The code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.img {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    position:relative;
}

div.img:hover {
    border: px solid #777;
}

div.img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#NomeAnime {
    position:relative;
    width:98%;
    left:2px;
    top:-20%; /* Posição vertical */
    color: white; /* Cor do texto */
    font: bold 13px arial, sans-serif; /* Fonte */
    text-align: center; /* Alinhamento */
    height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="img">
    <img src="http://iv1.lisimg.com/image/7814282/600full-asa-butterfield.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
<div id="NomeAnime">teste</div></div>
</div>

<div class="img">
    <img src="http://iv1.lisimg.com/image/7814282/600full-asa-butterfield.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
<div id="NomeAnime">teste</div></div>

<div class="img">
    <img src="http://iv1.lisimg.com/image/7814282/600full-asa-butterfield.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
<div id="NomeAnime">teste</div></div>
</div>

<div class="img">
    <img src="http://iv1.lisimg.com/image/7814282/600full-asa-butterfield.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="600" height="400">
<div id="NomeAnime">teste</div></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please translate your post to English!

Comment: Uhm, it would be nice if you could translate your question to English :-)

Comment: I'm a beginner in HTML, and I'm trying to create ma grid and images, and I want to flip the text over the image, but I can not. Would anyone help me? I did several tests and nothing worked. I'm studying this if I stop, and gradually I'm getting it, but this time I need help. The code:

Comment: `id` elements must be unique to the html page. (you have `NomeAnime` listed multiple times

Comment: @David Benner, you can also post on stackoverflow in portuguese (voce pode postar no stackoverflow em portugues) http://pt.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.img {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    height: 10px;
    position:relative;
}

div.img:hover {
    border: px solid #777;
}

div.img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#NomeAnime {
    position:relative;
    width:98%;
    left:2px;
    top:-20px; /* Posição vertical */
    color: white; /* Cor do texto */
    font: bold 13px arial, sans-serif; /* Fonte */
    text-align: center; /* Alinhamento */
    height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="img">
    <img src="http://iv1.lisimg.com/image/7814282/600full-asa-butterfield.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
    <div id="NomeAnime">teste</div>
</div>

<div class="img">
    <img src="http://iv1.lisimg.com/image/7814282/600full-asa-butterfield.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
    <div id="NomeAnime">teste</div>
</div>

<div class="img">
    <img src="http://iv1.lisimg.com/image/7814282/600full-asa-butterfield.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
<div id="NomeAnime">teste</div>
</div>

<div class="img">
    <img src="http://iv1.lisimg.com/image/7814282/600full-asa-butterfield.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="600" height="400">
    <div id="NomeAnime">teste</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change you `id="NomeAnime"` to `class="NomeAnime"`, because the `id` identifier should be unique for each HTML node;

Change your css class declaration from `#NomeAnime` to `.NomeAnime` to match the class selector;

And finally, change your `position:relative` to 'position:absolute' and `top:-20%' to`top:20%` or as your want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.img {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    position:relative;
}

div.img:hover {
    border: px solid #777;
}

div.img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.NomeAnime {
    position:absolute;
    width:98%;
    left:2px;
    top:20%; /* Posição vertical */
    color: white; /* Cor do texto */
    font: bold 13px arial, sans-serif; /* Fonte */
    text-align: center; /* Alinhamento */
    height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="img">
    <img src="http://iv1.lisimg.com/image/7814282/600full-asa-butterfield.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
<div class="NomeAnime">teste</div></div>
</div>

<div class="img">
    <img src="http://iv1.lisimg.com/image/7814282/600full-asa-butterfield.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
<div class="NomeAnime">teste</div></div>

<div class="img">
    <img src="http://iv1.lisimg.com/image/7814282/600full-asa-butterfield.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
<div class="NomeAnime">teste</div></div>
</div>

<div class="img">
    <img src="http://iv1.lisimg.com/image/7814282/600full-asa-butterfield.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="600" height="400">
<div class="NomeAnime">teste</div></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have changed the text block to rotate on hover. Just try this one

```
div.img {
        margin: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        float: left;
        width: 180px;
        position: relative;
    }

    div.img:hover {
        border: px solid #777;
    }

    div.img img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    #NomeAnime {
        position: relative;
        width: 98%;
        left: 2px;
        top: -20%;
        /* Posição vertical */
        color: white;
        /* Cor do texto */
        font: bold 13px arial, sans-serif;
        /* Fonte */
        text-align: center;
        /* Alinhamento */
        height: 16px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: green;
        -moz-transition: -moz-transform ease 0.6s;
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform ease 0.6s;
        -o-transition: -o-transform ease 0.6s;
        -ms-transition: -ms-transform ease 0.6s;
        transition: transform ease 0.6s;
    }

    div.img:hover #NomeAnime {
        color: #00FF22;
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="img">
    <img src="http://iv1.lisimg.com/image/7814282/600full-asa-butterfield.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
    <div id="NomeAnime">
        <span>teste</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="img">
    <img src="http://iv1.lisimg.com/image/7814282/600full-asa-butterfield.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
    <div id="NomeAnime">
        <span>teste</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="img">
    <img src="http://iv1.lisimg.com/image/7814282/600full-asa-butterfield.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
    <div id="NomeAnime">
        <span>teste</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="img">
    <img src="http://iv1.lisimg.com/image/7814282/600full-asa-butterfield.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="600" height="400">
    <div id="NomeAnime">
        <span>teste</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/Jaffar29sha/nc7a09ns/1/

Comment: @DavidBanner, If the answer is not met your expectation, so what's your need?